# Grails Unit Test "CreateAlias" doesn´t work

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to make a unit test over a namedquery method and it´s not working as I am using the method grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.createAlias which doesn´t seem to be found by Grails: " No signature of method: grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.createAlias()"

I guess the problem is that when making a unit test and mocking the class, it´s trying to find the method around "**grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder**" class and not **grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder** class,  why ??  any ideas to solve it?

```
class Book{
  static namedQueries = {     
      testMethod()
      {
         createAlias('name', 'james')
      }
   }
}



@Mock([Book])
class BookTests{
  @Test
  void myTest() {
      Book.testMethod();
   }
}
```

**Error :  No signature of method: grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.createAlias()**

Answer (score 2):

We couldn't figure this out either; we suspect it's just missing from the GORM UnitTest implementation.  But if you just want to query an association, in Grails you don't need an alias.  Observe:

```
Book.createCriteria {
    eq("title", "One Hundred Years of Solitude")
    author {
        eq("name", "Gabriel García Márquez")
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, sometimes you do need an alias - it's the only way to specify a left join.  So ```Book.withCriteria { createAlias('author', 'a', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN) or { isNull('a.name')  eq ('a.name', 'Fred') } }``` would be quite useful to be able to test, but as far as I know, it's not testable any way anyhow - someone please show me I'm wrong!

Comment: It looks like usage of `createAlias()` is a restriction in groovy indeed http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/createAlias-in-gorm-unit-test-td4648894.html